# Why can't this std::find compare these objects

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Usually when I do an std::find I'll put a predicate as the third argument, but this time I thought I'd do it differently, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct RenderJob
{
    RenderJob() {};
    int renderJob_ID;
    bool operator==(RenderJob& rhs) { return rhs.renderJob_ID == this->renderJob_ID; }
};

int main()
{
    RenderJob foo;
    RenderJob foo2;
    foo == foo2; // Works

    std::vector<RenderJob> renderJobs;

    std::find(renderJobs.begin(), renderJobs.end(), foo); // Doesn't work
}
```

> binary "==" no operator found  which takes a left-handed operand of
>   type RenderJob (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Edit:: Well thanks for the answers. Here are some examples of why it fails

```
    RenderJob foo;
    RenderJob foo2;
    foo == foo2; // Works

    std::vector<RenderJob> renderJobs;

    std::vector<RenderJob>::const_iterator constit = renderJobs.begin();

    *constit == foo2;  // Doesn't work
```

Even simpler as an illustration:

```
 const RenderJob* pToRenderJob;

*pToRenderJob == foo2;  // This fails because the pointed to 
                        // object is const, and cannot call the 
                        // operator== function because the actual function
                        // definition is not const.
```

If it were the other way around:

```
foo2 == *pToRenderJob; // This would fail because the 
                        // operator==(RenderJob&) the actual argument 
                        // is not const. Very subtle rules
```

Comment: In your examples you can't do `*constit == foo2` or `*pToRenderJob == foo2` because the `operator==` is not declared to allow a `const` left operand to become `*this`.  It would be the same thing if the class had a function `void f();` - you could not do `constit->f()` or `pToRenderJob->f()`. But if you change that function to `void f() const;`, both those would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, the many rules are slowly setting in.

Comment: You should also defines `renderJob_ID` inside your class: `int renderJob_ID{}`. Leaving uninitialized object is premature optimization. In your example foo.renderJob_ID and foo.renderJob_ID have *indeterminate value* and if you declare `std::vector<RenderJob> renderJobs(10)` to create a vector of 10 `renderJobs`, all this 10 objects will have their renderJob_ID holding an *indeterminate value*. So your code will continue not to work, even after adding const to the operator== argument.

Answer (score 14):

You left your `const` qualifiers off.

```
bool operator==(const RenderJob& rhs) const { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Particularly the const RenderJob, not the one after the function. I don't get this though, I can compare them myself because of the operator== overload, doesn't the std::find just use the operator== function?

Comment: Both should be const. When the compiler is looking for an operator on const data, it will refuse to consider operators that do not guarantee const behavior.

Comment: I'm understanding now, but still, in my further example in the question, the right hand side is non const and so I thought should call the non-const operator==, unless of course there's a problem generally with comparing const and non-const.

Comment: Non-const objects can be promoted to const objects. Remember, const just means that an object is tagged as “you are not allowed to modify it”, regardless of the actual modifiability of the object.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like a const-correctness problem. Try something like this instead:

```
bool operator==(RenderJob const &rhs) const { 
    return rhs.renderJob_ID == this->renderJob_ID; 
}
```

Doing the comparison yourself worked because you were just passing plain objects that weren't temporaries, nor were they const qualified. With `std::find`, the comparison function will (at least usually) receive a reference to the object in the collection (which will normally be const qualified), so it needs to be able to receive a const-qualified reference.

Comment: Oh, I see, it worked. But, I was able to compare them myself. Doesn't the compare function in std::find just use the operator== function?

Comment: @Zebrafish `find` takes the value to compare to by const reference.

Answer (score 3):

> But that still doesn't make sense, in the above example, the right hand side is `foo2`, which is not constant, which should go to the non-`const` `operator==`. Unless there's a general rule that `const` and non `const` can't be compared.

There is no rule in the language that `const` and non-`const` objects cannot be compared. You have to make sure that they can be compared by using proper `const` qualifiers.

The line

```
*pToRenderJob == foo2;
```

is equivalent to

```
pToRenderJob->operator==(foo2);
```

That does not work since `pToRenderJob` cannot be used to call a non-`const` member function. `foo2` is not the problem here.

If you use

```
foo2 == *pToRenderJob
```

it is equivalent to

```
foo2.operator==(*pToRenderJob)
```

That is also a problem since the argument to the function is a `const` object while your function expects a non-`const` reference. Once again, `foo2` is not the problem.

Making the function a `const` member function and making the argument a `const` reference makes sure that all combinations of `const` and non-`const` objects on both sides of the operator can be used without any problem.

Comment: That is very interesting, so in the *pToRenderJob == foo2 that worked when I made the actual function const. Very interesting, and subtle rules.

Comment: @Zebrafish. It takes a while to get used to these rules but more than that, with a deeper understanding of the language, the rules start to make sense.